# How to change the behaviour of the smiley feature in CKEditor

Tags: html, email, ckeditor

We use CKEditor to construct emails. Now, when activating the smiley button, the smileys are actually added as

`<img alt="smiley" src="<app>/script/webeditor/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/regular_smile.png" />`

Of course, in an email we can not refer to an internal application URL. So, what are the options here?

- Gmail solves this by adding the smileys as inline images of the email
- Hotmail solves this by referring to images on a public location
- I found documentation about 'BBCode-mode' of the ckeditor, which would add the smiley as [:-)] and let the application which shows the bbcode decide which picture to use.
- there are HTML codes to show smileys, but browser support seems to be poor.

My question: which option to use? Are there already plugins available that handle one of those options? Ideally, something like BBCode should be available as valid HTML, supported by all browsers, maybe there is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you how to do it with a fixed location for the images (like Hotmail). You have to set a config property like this:

```
config.smiley_path = "http://www.example.com/images/";
```

This should render

```
src="http://www.example.com/images/regular_smile.png"
```

Comment: thanks! I can add that meanwhile we use data URL's instead